# Is there an '@' equivalent in php? like we have @"C:\Users\Documents" in C#

Tags: c#, php, path

Every time specifying a path, i have to add additional '\' characters.
Is there a way we can have specify path

```
$path=@"C:\Users\Documents";//need this is php
```

instead of

```
$path="C:\\Users\\Documents";
```

Thanks in advance for sharing inputs

NOTE: Not looking for dirname().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, using single quotes

```
$path = 'C:\Users\Documents';
```

this may be useful: [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: last quote also must be single :)

Comment: sorry, that's the danger of copy&paste

Comment: Okay, it was that simple. Feel like a fool now. Much  thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

You can use single quoted strings. These don't handle escape sequences such as \n \r. You can compare the functionality of single quoted php strings with the behaviour in C# according to the respective documentation pages. In C#, @"" strings are called [verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx).

[PHP String Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

[MSDN String Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
$string_without_escape_sequence = '\t\n\r';
```

Comment: ^ for pointing out documentation. I searched for entire file path and directory docs.